# Error con la función disabled de JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un login que por medio de JS valida los datos introducidos por el usuario incluso antes de dar al botón de Ingresar. El problema radica en que cuando introduzco un Email y Password erróneos hay unas funciones que deshabilitan el botón y debo refrescar la página para poder intentarlo de nuevo. Creo que eso es un error.

HTML

```
<!-- login Form -->
<div class="form login">
    <div class="form-content">
        <header>Inicia sesion</header>
        <form id="frmlogin">
            <div class="field input-field">
                <input type="text" placeholder="usuario o correo" name="user_mail" class="input">
            </div>

            <div class="field input-field">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass" class="password">
                <i class='bx bx-hide eye-icon'></i>
            </div>

            <div class="otp">
                <h4>Ingrese Código</h4>
                <div class="cont-img">
                    <div class="img-column">
                        <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twofasapp"
                            target="_blank"><img src="https://imgur.com/KXb8jWa.png" alt="2fas" style="width:100%"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-column">
                        <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2"
                            target="_blank"><img src="https://imgur.com/7VOFuWB.png" alt="google-" style="width:100%"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-column">
                        <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.authenticator.authservice2"
                            target="_blank"><img src="https://imgur.com/wZteIl2.png" alt="totp" style="width:90%"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-column">
                        <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azure.authenticator"
                            target="_blank"><img src="https://imgur.com/FRBdbpS.png" alt="microsoft" style="width:95%"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field-otp">
                    <input class="inputOTP" type="number" disabled>
                    <input class="inputOTP" type="number" disabled>
                    <input class="inputOTP" type="number" disabled>
                    <span>-</span>
                    <input class="inputOTP" type="number" disabled>
                    <input class="inputOTP" type="number" disabled>
                    <input class="inputOTP" type="number" disabled>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field button-field">
                <button id="btnlogin" disabled>Ingresa</button>
            </div>

            <div class="form-link">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="link forgot-pass">¿Olvidaste tu password?</a>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="line"></div>

        <div class="form-link">
            <span>¿No tienes una cuenta? <a href="javascript:;" class="link signup-link">Registrate</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
const forms = document.querySelector(".forms"),
    showPass = document.querySelectorAll(".eye-icon"),
    inpt = document.querySelectorAll(".inputOTP"),
    frm = document.querySelectorAll("form"),
    lin = document.querySelectorAll(".link"),
    ppass = document.querySelector("#preg_pass1"),
    pgass = document.querySelector("#preg_pass2"),
    chk = document.querySelector("#chck"),
    umail = document.querySelector('[name="user_mail"]'),
    pas = document.querySelector('[name="pass"]'),
    pmail = document.querySelector('[name="preg_mail"]'),
    rrp = document.querySelector('[name="respuesta"]');

let ps = 0;
showPass.forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", () => {
        e.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".password").forEach((t) => {
            if ("password" === t.type) return (t.type = "text"), void e.classList.replace("bx-hide", "bx-show");
            (t.type = "password"), e.classList.replace("bx-show", "bx-hide");
        });
    });
}),

inpt.forEach((e, t) => {
    e.addEventListener("keyup", (a) => {
        const s = e,
            n = e.nextElementSibling,
            r = e.previousElementSibling;
        s.value.length > 1
            ? (s.value = "")
            : (2 == t && "SPAN" == n.tagName && (n.nextElementSibling.removeAttribute("disabled"), n.nextElementSibling.focus()),
              n && n.hasAttribute("disabled") && "" !== s.value && (n.removeAttribute("disabled"), n.focus()),
              "Backspace" === a.key &&
                  inpt.forEach((e, a) => {
                      t <= a && r && (3 == a && "SPAN" == r.tagName && r.previousElementSibling.focus(), e.setAttribute("disabled", !0), (s.value = ""), r.focus());
                  }),
              inpt[5].disabled || "" === inpt[5].value ? (btnlogin.disabled = !0) : (btnlogin.disabled = !1));
    });
}),

lin.forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        switch ((e.preventDefault(), e.target.className)) {
            case "link signup-link":
                forms.classList.add("show-signup");
                break;
            case "link forgot-pass":
                forms.classList.add("show-forgot");
                break;
            case "link login-link":
                forms.classList.remove("show-signup"), forms.classList.remove("show-forgot");
        }
        frm.forEach((e) => {
            e.reset();
        }),
            ppass.classList.add("d-none"),
            pgass.classList.add("d-none"),
            chk.classList.add("d-none"),
            (InPreguta.innerHTML = "");
    });
}),

umail.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    "admin" == e.target.value.toLowerCase() ? (document.querySelector(".otp").classList.add("d-none"), (btnlogin.disabled = !1)) : (document.querySelector(".otp").classList.remove("d-none"), (btnlogin.disabled = !0));
}),

umail.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    e.target.value.length > 0 ? ps++ : ps--, otp_ready(2 == ps);
}),

pas.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    e.target.value.length > 0 ? ps++ : ps--, otp_ready(2 == ps);
});

const otp_ready = (e) => {
    e ? ((inpt[0].disabled = !1), inpt[0].focus()) : (inpt[0].disabled = !0);
};

pmail.addEventListener("blur", function (e) {
    e.target.value.length > 0 &&
        FetchAsynAwait("root/query/query.php", { preg_mail: e.target.value }, "text").then((e) => {
            isNumber(CLearChar(e.trim())) ? (tshow("danger", "¡ERROR!", "<br>El email no existe", 4500), (btnforgot.disabled = !0)) : ((btnforgot.disabled = !1), (InPreguta.innerHTML = e));
        });
}),

rrp.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    laRes(e);
}),

rrp.addEventListener("blur", function (e) {
    laRes(e);
});

const laRes = (e) => {
    e.target.value.length > 0 &&
        FetchAsynAwait("root/query/query.php", { respuesta: e.target.value, email: pmail.value }, "text").then((e) => {
            "ok" == CLearChar(e.trim()) ? (ppass.classList.remove("d-none"), pgass.classList.remove("d-none"), chk.classList.remove("d-none"), (btnforgot.disabled = !1)) : ((btnforgot.disabled = !0), tshow("danger", "¡ERROR!", e, 4500));
        });
};

btnforgot.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(),
        spin(btnforgot),
        FetchAsynAwait("root/query/recupera_pass.php", { JsonPars: JsonPars(frmforgot) }, "text").then((e) => {
            let t = CLearChar(e.trim());
            spin(btnforgot, !1, "Solicita"),
                "ok" == t
                    ? (tshow("success", "¡EXITO!", "<br>Su nueva password ha sido guardada", 3500),
                      setTimeout(() => {
                          location.reload();
                      }, 3500))
                    : "correo" == t
                    ? (tshow("success", "¡EXITO!", "<br>Su nueva password ha sido guardada<br>El correo se envio con la nueva imagen", 4500),
                      setTimeout(() => {
                          location.reload();
                      }, 4500))
                    : (spin(btnforgot, !1, "Solicita"), tshow("danger", "¡ERROR!", e, 4500));
        });
}),

btnlogin.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(), spin(btnlogin);
    let t = pas;
    if (0 == umail.value.length) spin(btnlogin, !1, "Ingresa"), tshow("warning", "¡VACIO!", "<br>Ingrese su usuario o email", 4500);
    else if (0 == t.value.length) spin(btnlogin, !1, "Ingresa"), tshow("warning", "¡VACIO!", "<br>Ingrese su password", 4500);
    else {
        let e = "";
        inpt.forEach(function (t) {
            e += t.value;
        }),
            FetchAsynAwait("root/query/valida.php", { JsonPars: JsonPars(frmlogin), otp: e }, "text").then((e) => {
                isNumber(CLearChar(e.trim()))
                    ? location.reload()
                    : (spin(btnlogin, !1, "Ingresa"),
                      tshow("danger", "¡ERROR!", e, 4500),
                      (btnlogin.disabled = !0),
                      inpt.forEach(function (e) {
                          (e.value = ""), (e.disabled = !0);
                      }),
                      (inpt[0].disabled = !1),
                      inpt[0].focus());
            });
    }
}),

btnregistro.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(),
        spin(btnregistro),
        FetchAsynAwait("root/query/registro.php", { json: JsonPars(frmregister) }, "text").then((e) => {
            "ok" == CLearChar(e.trim())
                ? (tshow("success", "¡REGISTRADO!", "<br>Revise su correo e ingrese nuevamente", 3500),
                  setTimeout(() => {
                      location.reload();
                  }, 3500))
                : (spin(btnregistro, !1, "Registrate"), tshow("danger", "¡ERROR!", e, 4500));
        });
});

const FetchAsynAwait = async (e, t, a = "json") => {
        const s = { method: "POST", cache: "no-cache", body: JSON.stringify(t), headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };
        try {
            const t = await fetch(e, s);
            return "json" === (await a) ? t.json() : t.text();
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    },
    JsonPars = (e) => {
        let t = new FormData(e),
            a = {};
        return (
            t.forEach(function (e, t) {
                a[t] = e;
            }),
            a
        );
    },
    CLearChar = (e) =>
        (e = (e = (e = (e = (e = (e = (e = (e = (e = (e = (e = (e = (e = (e = (e = e.replace('"', "")).replace("\ufeff", "")).replace(".", "")).replace(":", "")).replace(",", "")).replace(";", "")).replace("-", "")).replace(
            "(",
            ""
        )).replace(")", "")).replace("*", "")).replace("+", "")).replace('"', "")).replace("[", "")).replace("]", "")).replace(" ", "")),
    spin = (e, t = !0, a = "") => {
        t ? ((e.disabled = !0), (e.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></i>')) : ((e.disabled = !1), (e.innerHTML = a));
    };
function isNumber(e) {
    return /^-?[\d.]+(?:e-?\d+)?$/.test(e);
}
```

Validador

```
<?php
include '../conn/conn.php';

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$out = array();

$user_mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, $json['JsonPars']['user_mail']);
$pass = md5($json['JsonPars']['pass']);
$otp = $json['otp'];

if (empty($user_mail)) $out[] = '<br>Ingrese el usuario o correo';
if (empty($pass)) $out[] = '<br>Ingrese el password';
if ($user_mail == 'admin') {
    if (count($out) == 0) {
        $qA = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM users where user = '" . $user_mail . "' and password ='" . $pass . "' ");
        $rA = $qA->fetch_row();
        if ($qA->num_rows > 0) {
            if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
            $_SESSION['idUser'] = $rA[0];
            $out[] = $rA[0];
        } else {
            $out[] = '<br>Error en las Credenciales';
        }
    }
} else {
    $checkOTP = '';
    if (empty($otp)) $out[] = '<br>Abra su App Autenficador e ingrese el codigo mostrado';
    if (filter_var($user_mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        $qA = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM users where email = '" . $user_mail . "'");
    else
        $qA = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM users where user = '" . $user_mail . "'");
    $rA = $qA->fetch_row();
    if ($qA->num_rows == 0) {
        $out[] = '<br>No existe el usuario en nuestra bbdd';
    } else {
        if ($rA[3] != $pass) $out[] = '<br>Error en las Credenciales';
        if ($rA[4] == 0) $out[] = '<br>Administracion ha negado o no autoriza su acceso';
        if ($rA[5] == 0) $out[] = '<br>Su email aun no ha sido verificado';
        require '../auth2fa/auth2fa.php';
        $auth2fa = new auth2fa();
        $checkOTP = $auth2fa->verificar($rA[9], $otp, 2);
    }
    if (!$checkOTP) $out[] = '<br>No pudimos verificar su OTP';
    if (count($out) == 0) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
        $_SESSION['idUser'] = $rA[0];
        $out[] = $rA[0];
    }
}
echo $out[0];
```

El resto lo llevo bien (voy siguiendo un proyecto). Hasta el momento he leído y según algunos post, puede ser porque en el archivo JS se está usando `=` en lugar de `==` para "asignar" la función disabled.

Pero también veo que el script usa `btnlogin.disabled = !1` en lugar de `btnlogin.disabled = 0`, o sea, en lugar de asignar un valor de 0 o 1 asigna un valor diferente a 0 o 1, o simplemente usar `btnlogin.disabled = true` o `btnlogin.disabled = false`. La verdad no entiendo por qué lo hacen de esa forma o si es la adecuada.

PD: La consola no me muestra error alguno...

Comment: De hecho que `==` es una comparación, no una asignación (`=`). También me parece _particular_ que se utilice `!1` o `!0` en lugar de `false` o `true`.

Comment: Claro pero al final al cambiarlo no hace nada. El problema es que como se hace una búsqueda instantánea en la DB con JS, cuando no hay coincidencias, el botón y el evento submit se deshabilitan y me quedo sin poder hacer nada. 

Alguna ida???

Comment: think out of the box ... piensa fuera de la caja ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 ya cambié todo lo que podía, si solicito ayuda es porque me quede sin ideas. Think about it !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En efecto, como lo dice el titulo, el problema el la función `disabled`. En parte la asignación estaba mal.

Pero lo mejor fue depurar los errores con `console.log()`. Para ello me tuvo que dar una luz **@gbianchi**.

Código Final

```
FetchAsynAwait("root/core/login.php", { JsonPars: JsonPars(frmlogin), otp: e }, "text").then((e) => {
    if(isNumber(CLearChar(e.trim()))){
        location.reload()
    }
    else{
        (spin(btnlogin, 0, "Prueba otra vez"),
        tshow("danger", "¡ERROR!", e, 4500),
        (btnlogin.disabled = 0),
        inpt.forEach(function (e) {
            (e.value = ""), (e.disabled = 1);
        }),
        (inpt[0].disabled = 0),
        inpt[0].focus());
    }
});
```